# need to create login page in web site using Facebook login with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I need to create an Login page which uses Facebook account. I have seen code in PHP language but i want to use it in asp.net how should I use it and how it will retrieve my data with Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)

Comment: where should i put this facebook c# sdk after downloading means in which folder please help me ?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation). It says all.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna take a look: http://developers.facebook.com/

More specifically here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/

Comment: do i need to put any other binary file or source file into my code expect this thing